# auto indentation in vim is broken with first comment block in c++ file

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

I want to use auto indentation in vim which normally works well. I use `gg=G` to auto format my sources.

but now I get the following trouble:

```
class X
{
    public:
        void foo()
        {
        }

        /*
        Check
        After this comment block the indentation changes
        Next method goes to previous column
        */
    void bar()
    {
    }
};
```

How can I change the behavior that after the first comment block the indentation goes back for a column?

Comment: Select all source code using shift+v and press =

Comment: @AbdulRehman Can you try to read the question? :-) It is not regarding how to start auto indentation, but why the indentation is wrong or which params to change to get the wanted result. Also shift+v did not select everything. It starts visual mode for a single line. Also not helpful...

Comment: I don't know the answer of your question but shift+v and down arrow will select the lines of code and then you press  = it will indent them. I use :set ai to autoindent.

Comment: Also try :set cindent :) I typed your source code after this parameter It works.

Comment: On ym vim it doesn't work. As read from vim use mailing list: Its a known bug! Fixed in last September. My vim version is a view days older :-(

Comment: I have Vim  version 7.4.52, I don't have any issue of indentation.